# Accessing COM-dll via imported type library fails

Tags: .net, delphi, dll, com, typelib

I'm trying to use a .NET COM-dll which is part of the SDK for a stepper motor control interface. The SDK provides a type library, which I imported into Delphi via 'Import Component > Import a Type Library'.

Although I know some basics about COM programming, I struggle to get the interface working. The problem seems to be that the CoClass as well as the OLE Server Proxy only expose an empty interface, i.e. an interface without any methods (*_ComMotorCommands*). Casting from there to the actual *IComMotorCommands* yields an *Interface not supported* error.

```
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IComMotorCommands
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {0D4E3A3F-0C07-438B-9F6F-CC1968408CFC}
// *********************************************************************//
  IComMotorCommands = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{0D4E3A3F-0C07-438B-9F6F-CC1968408CFC}']
    function Get_ErrorFlag: WordBool; safecall;
    function Get_ErrorMessageString: WideString; safecall;    
    function Get_ErrorNumber: Integer; safecall;
    ...
  end;

...

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: _ComMotorCommands
// Flags:     (4432) Hidden Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {5AB3EB9E-E847-3133-95DC-4DDC7870C02A}
// *********************************************************************//
  _ComMotorCommands = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{5AB3EB9E-E847-3133-95DC-4DDC7870C02A}']
  end;

...

  CoComMotorCommands = class
    class function Create: _ComMotorCommands;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _ComMotorCommands;
  end;
```

I have also tried to create the interface manually via

```
CreateComObject(CLASS_ComMotorCommands) as IComMotorCommandsDisp
```

which itself does not throw an exception. Even setting some connection properties such as port and baud rate seem to work. But as soon as I try to query the motor status, I get

**'BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)'**,

mind you, **not** as an exception in my application, but via the error reporting mechanism of the interface itself (*Get_ErrorMessageString*).

This error usually indicates a bitness-conflict between x86 and x64 code. But my platform target is x86, as is the SDK. I'm running Delphi XE3 on Windows 7 x64, but the same error also appeared on a 32bit machine i tried, which does not make any sense to me.

The SDK also offers a couple of Visual Studio examples for VB, C++ and C#. But all of them use the Visual Studio-way of calling the interface and are of no help to me. (There you reference the TLB directly, simply declare a variable of type 'ComMotorCommands' and can then access all interface methods freely.)

I will provide full files on request via email.

I'm in over my head here, so any help on this would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: It perhaps is a bitness conflict. Run the program under Dependency Viewer in profile mode and see which module load triggers the error. Then check that module for being 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks David! But I'm not quite sure what specifically you mean by 'Dependency Viewer in profile mode'. Could you point me the right way, please?

Comment: Sorry. It's called Dependency Walker. Google it. Load it up. Go to profile menu item. Select your exe. And then go. You'll get loads of diagnostics and hopefully will isolate the module that is failing to load.

Comment: Oh, Dependency Walker! I already have this installed. I just had it walk over the application exe. But the profiling option is grayed out, as it is a 32bit exe on a 64bit system, which apparently doesn't work. BUT, the tool shows literally hundreds of dependancies - all of them 64bit and marked red ('different CPU type'). I have no clue what to make of this...

Comment: All those problems are because you are running 64 bit Dependency Walker. Use the 32 bit version.

Comment: You are right, with the x86 version the results are different. The profiler did indeed find a x64 dependancy: 'rs485_com.dll', which is part of the SDK and apparently handles low-level communication with the hardware. The bitness conflict seems to accur when the COM server tries to call rs485_com.dll. I'll have to see if I can obtain the x86 version of this file somehow. Anyway, thanks for your help in getting me this far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem most likely is an attempt to load a 64 bit module. Debug this with Dependency Walker in profile mode.

Comment: Again, thanks for your help, David. I was able to track down a 32bit version of rs485_com.dll. Now the interface works beautifully!